# OpenSSL: bad decrypt 3872:error:0607F08A

Tags: encryption, openssl

I'm trying to make a encrypted pass-file, but receive an error:

> bad decrypt
>   3872:error:0607F08A:digital envelope routines:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length:.\crypto\evp\evp_enc.c:414:

please, provide a solution for present error

here is command for making file:

> openssl enc -des-ede-cbc -K 16161616161616161515151515151515 -iv
>   000000000000000 -in C:\OpenSSL\bin\ssl\key\pass.txt -out
>   C:\OpenSSL\bin\ssl\key\pass.enc -nopad

pass.txt contains just one line with pass

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working for me if I leave out the "-nopad" argument:

> openssl enc -des-ede-cbc -K 16161616161616161515151515151515 -iv
>   000000000000000 -in C:\OpenSSL\bin\ssl\key\pass.txt -out
>   C:\OpenSSL\bin\ssl\key\pass.enc