# Can't decrypt AES-256-CBC encrypted data correctly with openssl

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm trying to decrypt data provided by 3rd party resource.

Openssl fails to decrypt data with error:

```
error:0606508A:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length
```

I've tried decrypt online and it works, here is [link](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc/index?key=1313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313&iv=00000000000000000000000000000000&input=673826A18BAA1F18F70E89523F8CCA7F&mode=cbc&action=Decrypt&output=).

Code example:

```
    $result = openssl_decrypt(
        $bin,
        'AES-256-CBC',
        hex2bin($this->key),
        OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,
        hex2bin($this->iv)
    );

    if (!$result) {
        while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
        {
            echo "ERROR: " . $msg;
        }
    }
```

Data :

```
Input:673826A18BAA1F18F70E89523F8CCA7F
Key:1313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313
IV:00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Decrypt used with zero padding, which shouldn't add any PKCS paddings as far as I understand.

Input length will be 16 bytes which is block size for AES (128 bits)

System - Windows 10
OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
PHP 7.1.1

I can't figure out where is error. Please help out.

**UPDATE 1**

Received same error in console:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -base64 -in .\in -out .\out -K 1313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -nopad

    bad decrypt
2820:error:0607F08A:digital envelope routines:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length:evp_enc.c:412:
```

Data is 16 bytes:

```
>>> strlen(base64_decode('ZzgmoYuqHxj3DolSP4zKfw=='));
=> 16
```

Comment: Possibly related to `-nopad` option? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858373/openssl-bad-decrypt-3872error0607f08a

Comment: Block size is 16 bytes exactly, without this option i'm getting garbage data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your flag from:

```
OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING
```

to:

```
OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING
```

[Based on documents](http://php.net/manual/de/function.openssl-decrypt.php), input should be Base64 encoded if `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` is not specified. The code should be like this:

```
$result = openssl_decrypt(
        $bin,
        'AES-256-CBC',
        hex2bin($this->$key),
        OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,
        hex2bin($this->$iv)
    );

    if (!$result) {
        while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
        {
            echo "ERROR: " . $msg;
        }
    }
```

Your input data is not Base64 encoded. In your command line, you create same problem with specifying `-base64` option.

Comment: It might be that `$bin` is not hex *decoded* either. That would not generate a bad block size error, but it would still not generate the right result and - most likely - a padding error.

Comment: @Afshin you are right. I knew about that behaviour but was getting some corrupted data (as I thought), but seems like if convert that binary result to hex - I'll get string i need. Thank you for help